# Concatenate properties in Symfony2 buildForm()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a set of entities in Doctrine which depends on each other to build certain data, and I need to create a form which uses data from two of those entities.

I have a Magazine entity, an Issue entity and a Chapter entity. The Magazine (Mag1, Mag2) has it's name, the Issue, that belongs to only one Magazine, has it's 'number' (Mag1->Issue 1, Mag1->Issue 2, Mag3-> Issue 1, Mag2 -> Issue 'Summer'). The Chapter have to belong to just one Issue, but when creating the form, to build the Issue selector I need to concatenate properties from two entities:

```
class ChapterType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('number')
        ->add('issue', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Bundle:Issue',
                'property' => 'magazine.name'
        ))
    ;
}
...
```

What I need to do is concatenate in the 'property' something like `'magazine.name'+'number'` (where `'number'` is the Issue which will be added number. Trying to concatenate with the `.` like in php strings doesn't work since they aren't strings so I don't know what I have to do or if It's possible to do It this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Issue create a new getter that does the concat. Given that you have properly setup the ManyToOne relationship, the getter should be something like:

```
public function getMagazzineAndIssue() {
   return $this->magazine->getName() . $this->number;
}
```

in the form, use this new method as the property:

```
$builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('number')
    ->add('issue', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'Bundle:Issue',
            'property' => 'magazineAndIssue'
    ))
```

Comment: A more canonical solution would involve issuing a toString() method instead of getMagazzineAndIssue() and getting rid of the property parameter in the form. No property parameter defaults to using the toString() method.